# How to change user icon/avatar in app-launcher? (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, icons

Picture showing default user icon in application launcher

[image]

TL;DR how do I change the "Standard" user avatar seen at the top of the application launcher as seen in the picture?

(Application launcher closes/fades when I take a screen-shot, sorry for the inconvenience. It's still visible though)

Hello!

I recently decided to go all-in with gnu/linux and went for kubuntu. I'm still a newbie and so far I've been trying to get comfy by customizing the UI to my preferences using the various settings available.

But here's the problem, I can't seem to change the user icon/avatar that appears atop the application launcher. When hovering over it, I get the pointy hand that suggests that I can click it to go into some settings or something, but clicking does nothing. I've been searching all over but haven't found something to solve this yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have solved itself. The avatar has now updated.

I haven't done anything to specifically update it, though I suspect the times I have rebooted may have made a difference. Didn't notice it before now.

I was probably just being impatient.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the launcher from the panel and put it back again.

Comment: Please post some additional information about how to do it and add it to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the icon in the top left of the launcher next to the user name. In the dialog box that opens there are 2 sides, 1 to add a new user on the left and on to edit users on the right. On the right side click on the icon next to the user name and go from there.